# Using a textbox value for a file name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

How do you use a textbox value for VB to save some text to? This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butUpdate.Click
    Dim ECOLID As String
    ECOLID = txtID.Text
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("?", True)
    file.WriteLine("ECOL Number:")
    file.WriteLine(txtID.Text)
    file.Close()
End Sub
```

The txtID text will determine the title however how can I get it to save it as "C:/Order/'txtID'.txt" for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A textbox has a property called Name and this is (usually) the same as the variable name that represent the TextBox in your code.

So, if you want to create a file with the same name of your textbox you could write

```
 file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(txtID.Name & ".txt", True)
```

However there is a big improvement to make to your code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butUpdate.Click
    Dim ECOLID As String
    ECOLID = txtID.Text
    Dim fileName = txtID.Name & ".txt"
    Using file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(fileName, True)
        file.WriteLine("ECOL Number:")
        file.WriteLine(txtID.Text)
    End Using
End Sub
```

In this version the opening of the StreamWriter object is enclosed in a Using Statement. This is fundamental to correctly release the resources to the operating system when you have done to work with your file because the End Using ensures that your file is closed and disposed correctly also in case of exceptions